# Memory leaks in AppCompatEditText

Tags: android, memory-leaks, leakcanary

Does anyone know what causes this memory leak? I have no idea how to fix it

[image]

Comment: Some source code from the referenced classes would help.

Answer (score 2):

somewhere in your class you are storing the value of mContext as a variable which is which is not being destroyed when your activity recreates (e.g. rotates)

try to remove that mContext from that class or make sure that it gets destroyed with the activity.

Comment: This problem seems to be thrown from the source code(AppCompatEditText)

Comment: are you passing this view to some static variable?